# Suffix tree in Matlab

Tags: matlab, string-matching, suffix-tree

I am finding longest substring in text T, such that it is a prefix of string S. I have made algorithm using suffix tree which provides less complex solution, but since Matlab doesn't use pointers or any other reference, I am stuck at the implementation.

Could somebody please suggest some solution or some alternate way to this problem, possible in Matlab.

Comment: Any idea if we could use some reference object in Matlab structure field value to point to next structure object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions for using "pointers" in Matlab:

- You can simply use cell array indexes as pointers, to reference cell array elements.  This is probably the simplest approach.
- You can use a [Handle Class](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) for creating classes which you can hold references to.  A little more involved but very nice from a software engineering point of view.
- As less Matlaby solution, you could write the algorithm in C and use mex to interface between Matlab and your algorithm.

Comment: mex interface? I will google that. Because I think implementing a tree will be much simpler in C.

By the way, I will search on other suggestions also. Thanks for help

Comment: Any idea if we could use some reference object in Matlab structure field value?

Comment: Well, a struct field value can only store the same things as any other Matlab variable, so one of the first two options - a cell array index or a handle reference.